# Android JSON VOlley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Good Day, I would like to get data from [this url](http://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/), and I have problems with onResponse method implementation:

I have something like this:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/",

                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
//The Problem is here
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");
                                    String author = jsonArray.getString(0);
                                    textView.setText(author);

                               }catch(JSONException e){
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                               }
                            }
                        },

                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            }
                        }


                );
                requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            }
```

I don`t understand how to implement onResponse method correctly, I know that I must to get string from array or object, but data from link make me problems to understand what is it object or array, can you write me how to get author field from this url.
Thank you

Comment: read the doc: http://json.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the response in your link is JSONObject, you only need to do the following inside onResponse:

```
String author = response.getString("author");
textView.setText(author);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The response that you are getting is not a `JSONArray` but is a `JSONObject`. You could try the below code and see if you are able to get the author.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/",

                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                String author = response.get("author");
                                textView.setText(author);

                           }catch(JSONException e){
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                        }
                    },

                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }


            );
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The data from link is `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`. Call `response.getString("author");` to get author string.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    String author = response.getString("author");
} catch(JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```